# Oracle SQL auto rounding adjustment use select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select round(4.43,2) as result from dual;

result 
---------
4.43  <-------auto adjust to 4.45

select round(4.42,2) as result from dual;

result
---------
4.42   <-------auto adjust to 4.40
```

Hi , the above result all is correct, but how do I set auto rounding adjustment like this ?

```
example
4.41 = 4.40
4.42 = 4.40
4.43 = 4.45
4.46 = 4.45
4.47 = 4.45
4.48 = 4.50
4.49 = 4.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 4.41 from dual union all
  3     select 4.42 from dual union all
  4     select 4.43 from dual union all
  5     select 4.44 from dual union all
  6     select 4.45 from dual union all
  7     select 4.46 from dual union all
  8     select 4.47 from dual union all
  9     select 4.48 from dual union all
 10     select 4.49 from dual
 11    )
 12  select col,
 13         round(col / 0.05) * 0.05 result
 14  from test;

  COL RESULT
----- ------
 4,41   4,40
 4,42   4,40
 4,43   4,45
 4,44   4,45
 4,45   4,45
 4,46   4,45
 4,47   4,45
 4,48   4,50
 4,49   4,50

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```